# Is there a poster for Qt documentation?

Tags: qt, documentation, poster

I'm looking for a cheet-sheet style poster (or better posters) for a whole (parts of) Qt library. 
Is there such thing or something similar?

Comment: Like the MSDN Visual Studio posters you get when buying a copy?

Comment: MSDN style poster(s) would be perfect. But some kind of cheat sheet could be adopted as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a class chart](http://doc.trolltech.com/extras/qt43-class-chart.pdf) of version 4.3

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Qt 4.1 chart:

[Main Classes in Qt 4.1](http://doc.trolltech.com/extras/qt41-class-chart.pdf)

This one is a little better than the above:

[The Essential Qt 3.x Class Hierarchy](ftp://ftp.trolltech.com/qt/pdf/3.0/qt30-class-chart.pdf)

I guess they stopped getting fancy when Nokia bought them.